# Is there such a BST that has optimal height but does not satisfy the AVL condition?

Tags: data-structures

I'm curious whether it is possible to construct a binary search tree in such a way that it has minimal height for its n elements but it is not an AVL tree.

Or in other words, is every binary search tree with minimal height by definition also an AVL tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AVL requirement is that left and right depths differ at most by 1.

An optimal BST of N elements, where D = ²log N, has the property that sum of depths is minimal. The effect is that the depth of every element resides at most `ceil(D)` deep.

To have a minimal sum of depths the tree must be filled most full from the top on down, so the sum of individual lengths is minimal.

*Not optimal BST - and not AVL:*

```
          f
         / \
        a   q
           / \
          n   x
         / \   \
        j   p   y
```

- Elememts: 8
- Depts: 0 + 1 + 1 + 2 + 2 + **3** + **3** + 3 = 15

*Optimal BST - and AVL:*

```
          _ f _
         /     \
        j       q
       / \     / \
      a   n   p   x
                   \
                    y
```

- Elememts: 8
- Depts: 0 + 1 + 1 + 2 + 2 + **2** + **2** + 3 = 13

**So there is no non-AVL optimal BST.**